NMaximize not giving the global maximum of SmoothKernelDistribution of 2D data
data = {{4.66082, 0.391759}, {7.08804, 0.182339}, {8.53507, 0.720834}, {11.2089, 1.02641}, {6.66469, 0.413393}, {0.537794, 1.00807}, {0.669767, 0.519532}, {10.8742, 0.754568}, {11.201, 0.297006}, {5.93108, 0.463403}, {0.491355, 0.558849}, {3.09213, 0.100791}, {0.938854, 0.373559}, {10.4945, 0.558595}, {6.93745, 0.32596}, {6.77187, 0.140486}, {8.86438, 0.595298}, {8.30802, 0.932752}, {0.136879, 2.68426}, {5.4813, 0.775966}, {0.134283, 3.10756}, {1.98966, 0.327422}, {10.8185, 0.824564}, {0.521724, 0.163336}, {10.0636, 0.523144}, {5.04245, 0.832211}, {11.9701, 0.865195}, {0.474875, 0.418131}, {6.0871, 0.479452}, {10.2336, 0.756979}};
kde = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
NMaximize[{PDF[kde, {x, y}]}, {x, y}]

The output is {0.0793899, {x -> 1.29467, y -> 0.391787}}.
The actual maximum value is close to 0.1, which can be seen on the plot
ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[kde, {x, y}], {x, -2, 12}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

I can not find the mistake in the code.

Hi! ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[kde, {x, y}], {x, -2, 12}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic] shows  value is closer to 0.1.

Sorry for my previous stupid comment, you are completely right! It looks like it has some troubles dealing with the underlying interpolation function ... You can try fiddling with the method, for example: NMaximize[Evaluate@PDF[kde, {x, y}], {x, y}, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 100}] If you want to read more about this topic, see According to Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization.

Thanks for the edit to the question.  I tried your method and it worked. but still its having issues with other data set. I will go through the suggestion. Thanks.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{4.66082, 0.391759}, {7.08804, 0.182339}, {8.53507, 
    0.720834}, {11.2089, 1.02641}, {6.66469, 0.413393}, {0.537794, 
    1.00807}, {0.669767, 0.519532}, {10.8742, 0.754568}, {11.201, 
    0.297006}, {5.93108, 0.463403}, {0.491355, 0.558849}, {3.09213, 
    0.100791}, {0.938854, 0.373559}, {10.4945, 0.558595}, {6.93745, 
    0.32596}, {6.77187, 0.140486}, {8.86438, 0.595298}, {8.30802, 
    0.932752}, {0.136879, 2.68426}, {5.4813, 0.775966}, {0.134283, 
    3.10756}, {1.98966, 0.327422}, {10.8185, 0.824564}, {0.521724, 
    0.163336}, {10.0636, 0.523144}, {5.04245, 0.832211}, {11.9701, 
    0.865195}, {0.474875, 0.418131}, {6.0871, 0.479452}, {10.2336, 
    0.756979}};

kde = SmoothKernelDistribution[
   SetPrecision[data, 15],
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];

plt = Plot3D[PDF[kde, {x, y}], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
   PlotPoints -> 35,
   MaxRecursion -> 5,
   WorkingPrecision -> 13,
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, PDF}];

Starting estimate of peak
pt = MaximalBy[Last][Cases[plt, {{_, _, _} ..}, All][[1]]][[1]]

(* {9.53331, 0.631397, 0.104871} *)

Show[plt, Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pt]}]]


Using FindMaximum
FindMaximum[{PDF[kde, {x, y}]}, {{x, pt[[1]]}, {y, pt[[2]]}},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15] // N

(* FindMaximum::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local maximum. *)

(* {0.104871, {x -> 9.80813, y -> 0.631397}} *)


NMaximize[{PDF[kde, {x, y}]}, {x, y}, 
Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 200},  MaxIterations -> 1000]


0.102953,{x->9.80813,y->0.6857}}

